# Using Truth Tables to Solve Logic Riddles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, puzzle

I've been traversing the practice exercises in Kenneth Rosen's *[Discrete Math and Its Applications](https://notendur.hi.is/mbh6/html/_downloads/Discrete%20Mathematics%20and%20Its%20Applications%20-%20Kenneth%20Rosen%20(2012).pdf)* in preparation for an upcoming class that is heavily proofs-based.

Constructing truth tables from propositions has been relatively simple up to this point, but now I am having to use them to solve logic puzzles and I am struggling. I can, for the most part, reason through many of the problems with words, but I am specifically instructed to solve them using truth tables and I find this to be very difficult.

Translating statements into logical expressions is particularly challenging for me. For example, given the following puzzle:

> "The police have three suspects for the murder of Mr.
> Cooper: Mr. Smith, Mr. Jones, and Mr. Williams. Smith,
> Jones, and Williams each declare that they did not kill
> Cooper. Smith also states that Cooper was a friend of
> Jones and that Williams disliked him. Jones also states
> that he did not know Cooper and that he was out of town
> the day Cooper was killed. Williams also states that he saw both Smith and Jones with Cooper the day of the
> killing and that either Smith or Jones must have killed
> him.  Can you determine who the murderer was if one of the three men is guilty, the two innocent men
> are telling the truth, but the statements of the guilty
> man may or may not be true?"

how do I know what information to populate my truth table with? How am I supposed to represent a statement like

> "Smith also states that Cooper was a friend of Jones and that
> Williams disliked him."

using propositional logic? The fact that two people are friends, or that one person dislikes another, doesn't give me any concrete information that I can use to inform decisions, and I am worried that any assumptions I make (e.g. if person A likes person B, he would not kill him) could be incorrect and invalidate any further reasoning. I could construct truth table after truth table, but if the propositions I am evaluating are irrelevant, it renders the entire process useless.

Any general advice on solving these kinds of problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The usual idea is to try the various cases.  Pick two of the suspects and assume that they are telling the strict truth.  See if that leads to a contradiction.  Repeat for all choices  of the innocent pair.  Note, for instance, that $S$ says that $J$ and $C$ were friends but $J$ says he didn't know $C$.  That's a contradiction right there.

Comment: For a more literal transcription to propositional logic, you could start with the link between innocence and truth, and say for example $[\lnot Killer(Smith)] \rightarrow [Friend(Cooper, Jones) \land Disliked(Williams, Cooper)]$.  But then you would also have to encode some of the implicit dependencies, such as that being a friend or disliking both are in contradiction with "not knowing" somebody.  You also have the assumption $Killer(Smith) \lor Killer(Jones) \lor Killer(Williams)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If 2 of the 3 men contradict each other, then the 3rd man must be innocent, and therefore must be truthful in all of this statements.